# How to make Windows 10 run GT120 and GTX 980ti

Tags: bootcamp, windows, gpu

I can't make both cards work properly on Windows 10. Here's what I've tried.

I've got a successful Windows 10 installation over my Mac Pro (mid 2010) over Sierra, installed the boot camp drivers as recommended on this site. Everything is perfect.

My monitor is hooked to the GT 120 (to get access to EFI boot screen), Windows couldn't find the driver for it and found the GTX 980ti automatically. After the reboot request I could notice it wasn't working properly, the resolution screen was ok but you couldn't open any windows, they got stuck on the bottom bar and the icons beside the clock were missing.

Through the device manager, I uninstalled the GTX 980ti, asked for Windows to update the GT120 driver, it worked like a charm. After reboot Windows, it found automatically again GTX 980ti, installed it without asking for permission and requested to boot. Again, after booting we returned to the ground zero, GT120 didn't load the driver, and GTX 980ti remained with the same issue.

I'm not the Windows guy, so I do not even know if that is possible.

Please, any help would be welcome.

Comment: Which recommended site? You did not include a link. Are you using a EFI boot for Windows? Are you using Windows 10 Home or Pro editions?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for getting back. The site I mean this website, Ask Different. The Windows was installed using the BIOS boot method. I'm using Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used this tool for a while. When I did, the tool worked, but for me I found the tool badly designed and therefore difficult to use. Hopefully, Microsoft has improved this tool and you will have a better experience.

This tool will allow you to prevent an update from installing. [See the Microsoft website: How to temporarily prevent a Windows Update from reinstalling in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3183922/how-to-temporarily-prevent-a-windows-update-from-reinstalling-in-windo). There will be a link to download the "Show or hide updates" troubleshooter package.

Comment: I don't how windows deal with that, but if could delete one of the cards on the device manager and Windows do not add it again after a reboot, that solves the problem I guess.

Comment: This tool didn't help. I get the GT120 out of the computer and booted just with 980ti. It worked perfectly. What's causing that conflict I don't know, I guess windows can't handle two cards – Ricardo 12 hours ago